# I "will come" or "come" to see my grandma every week?

Tags: tense, present-tense, future-constructions

The original question goes:

> I ______ to see my grandma and help her with some housework every week.
>
> A. came
>
> B. am going come
>
> C. come
>
> D. will come

The given answer is D. However I think C is possible too.

When I was studying the present tense, my English teacher told us that "if you describe an event that will happen regularly, then you should use present tense". For instance, "I go hiking every week".

My understanding of this question and the answer is, that the speaker might be giving a promise for the future. Like he didn't come to see her grandma regularly before, but in the future he will come to see her grandma every week regularly.

But if he's describing an event that's already happening regularly? In that case, shouldn't the answer be C?

Am I wrong OR are the question & the answer wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both C and D are perfectly possible.

C means that this already happens - he comes to see *his* grandma (or *she* comes to see her grandma) every week.

D is, as you say, a promise for the future.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm losing my confidence because of the bad written questions in my homework (this question is one of them). Your answer rebuilds my confidence again, though not much.

Comment: In fact "A" is almost possible too. It is wrong because it should be parallel to "help".  But this question is almost like  "I own a ..."  (A) dog  (B) cat  (c) fish.   The meaning is different, but you can't choose an answer unless you know what the intended meaning is.